# If a permutation $f$ is not one way, what can we say about $f^{p(n)}$?

Tags: one-way-function

Consider a permutation $f:\{0,1\}^*\rightarrow \{0,1\}^*$, which is *not* a one-way function, i.e. there exists an efficient probabilistic adversary $\mathcal{A}$ and some polynomial $q(n)$ such that for infinitely many $n$

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Pr}[\mathcal{A}(f(x)) = x] > \frac{1}{q(n)},
\end{equation}
where the probability is over the internal randomness of $\mathcal{A}$ and  $x$ drawn uniformly at random from $\{0,1\}^n$.

I would now like to prove that $f^{p(n)}$ is not a one way function, for any polynomial $p(n)$. Is this true for all permutations $f$ which are not one way?

My intuition was that this would be true, and that one could prove this by showing that $\tilde{\mathcal{A}} = \mathcal{A}^{p(n)}$ is a suitable adversary for $f^{p(n)}$. However, I can't get this to work. Is there a clever way to prove this, or is the statement I am trying to prove actually false?

Comment: Let's considet the identity function as f.

Comment: I would like to understand whether _for all_ permutations $f$ which are not one way, $f^{p(n)}$ is also not one way. The identity function is an example of a specific permutation $f$ which is not one way, and for which $f^{p(n)}$ is also not one way for all $p(n)$. As such, it doesn't provide a counter example to the conjecture, it just provides one example of a specific function which has this property - I would really like to understand if this holds for all permutations which are not one way. I have edited the question slightly to make this clear.

Comment: I think this statement might be false because an adversary only needs to be successful for infinitely many $n$ and not all of them, so a non OWP f could be constructed as "return the first n-1 bits" if $n$ is even and "run this actual OWP $\pi$" if $n$ is odd, then this would be a non-OWF because for every second length there is an inverter but inverting twice is hard.

Comment: I don't think this construction works as a counter-example, because for $n$ even we have that $f:\{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^{n-1}$, and therefore $f$ is not a permutation for even $n$.

Comment: You are right, I was not precise enough on the permutation part, at least the above is still an instructive counter-example for the more general non-OWF case even if it doesn't work for non-OWPs. Maybe there is still a way to change the length of the output if we design a clever permutation say for every two or three consecutive bitlengths.

Comment: @SEJPM you are right - I also think that the construction is instructive for the more general case. Unfortunately I cannot see how to modify your ideas for the case of permutations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a permutation $f$ is not one way, we can not conclude about the one-wayness of $f^{p(n)}$. In fact, even $f^2$ could be one-way, if there are one-way length-preserving permutations that is.

Constructive proof: assume $g:\{0,1\}^*\rightarrow \{0,1\}^*$ is a length-preserving OWP, not invertible starting with rank $m$. Define $f$ from $g$ such that, for any bitstring $x$,

$$\begin{align}f(x\mathbin\|0)&=x\mathbin\|1\\f(x\mathbin\|1)&=g(x)\mathbin\|0\end{align}$$

$f$ is a permutation. It is trivially invertible for half its inputs of any fixed width, thus is not a OWP.

$f^2$ is also a permutation, with

$$\begin{align}f^2(x\mathbin\|0)&=g(x)\mathbin\|0\\f^2(x\mathbin\|1)&=g(x)\mathbin\|1\end{align}$$

An hypothetical algorithm that inverts $f^2$ starting at width $n>m$ could be used to invert $g$ at width $n-1\ge m$. With $g$ being a OWF, there is no such algorithm. Hence $f^2$ is one-way.

Comment: Straight from The Book  :)

Comment: How would a permutation *not* be length preserving?

Comment: @Maeher: how about the transformation $h:\{0,1\}^*\rightarrow \{0,1\}^*$ which leaves all bitstrings unchanged, except the all-zero bitstrings (including empty), with that of length $2k$ and $2k+1$ exchanged?